# Missing wysiwyg folder in magento

Tags: magento

When I try to upload some images on **CMS > Pages** in wysiwyg editor, I get an error:

> The directory is not writable by server.

I have already explored this error caused because of `media/wysiwyg` folder is missing. If I create this folder all will be fine.

But I wonder why this folder is missing after Magento installation. Can someone explain?

Comment: Same issue in 1.9.1. Interestingly enough, if you ignore the error message (assuming the write permissions are configured correctly in your file system) and just proceed uploading some content, e.g., images, Magento will create the media/wysiwyg folder and the error message is gone. This clearly does not answer your question as to "why" the folder is missing ... that is something best answered by Magento developers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whenever you get **Images not Uploading. Destination folder not writable**, **folder is not writable or does not exists** or either anything similar. Just follow the check-list below:

- **Permissions** : Check if the server has rights to write into var and media folders i.e write permissions.
- **Missing folders** : In the folder media, take a look if `media/catalog`, `media/wysiwyg` and `media/images` are there (or even any other folder you’ve set up to upload your files to). If yes, if the server has the permissions to write on them.
- **Var/cache** : Get yourself sure you run one `$ rm -rf var/cache/*` and got rid of everything inside this folder.
- **Cache Management** : Clean the blocks in **System > Cache Management**.

Comment: The link you posted goes to landing page for a hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

Basic thing I have found on this magento sysytem using wysiwyg editor is it will never let your upload media on root folder

If you create a sub folder using wysiwyg editor  you can update anything on it

:P

helpfull o me